# Почему — белокурый?

Tags: этимология

Блондинов называют еще белокурыми. Я понимаю, если бы было "белокуДрый", но откуда тут "курица"?))))

Answer (score 7):

Происхождение неясно. Есть разные объяснения. Например, от слова белокудрый,как вы и предположили,  - д потерялась со временем. Или от словосочетания "белая кура" -  "белая пыль" .

Answer (score 3):

Возможно, белокурые волосы - *светловьющиеся*. Белые + курчавые. **Куриться** - виться кольцами (о дыме). Дым волос - в поэзии нередко встречается. А вот неожиданный образ :

> Зри, ― восстав, дух бури несется по поверхности нив, колеблет желтые злаки и **оку очарованному Океан представляет белокурый**, на коем зрение тем паче услаждается, что зрит тут наполнившуюся уже надежду возделателя и совершившуюся благодать Природы на его прокормление. (Радищев, Нацкорпус)

Также близко сравнение девушки белокурой - с *лебедью белокрылой*. Старинная форма слова зафиксирована : *белокуроватая*...

Дополнение. Волосы не *пыльные*, а **пепельно-белокурые**. Пепел - продукт горения/**курения**. Как и белый дым.

"Изба белая или *белокурная изба* - топящаяся *по-белому*"

Answer (score 3):

Лев Успенский утверждает, что от "Кур" , что в древнерусском языке значило "пыль"
(у поляков и сейчас "пыль" - "kurz", "куж"). Следовательно, "белокурый"
-  "пыльно-белый", как бы припудренный   пылью.         http://www.pochemyneinache.com/alfavit/2/str49.html

Comment: Куржак - изморозь, "снежная пыль", но волосы пыльными не назовут, неэстетично это!)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Это лошадь *каурой* масти, причём по Фасмеру, - "Каурый Ближайшая этимология: "светло-гнедой (о лошадиной масти)", стар. **Курый** (1 раз; см. Срезн. I, 1380)"

Т.е. "белокурый" - вполне возможно бело-каурый, по-современному - "платиновый блонд" 
[image]

Другие версии про белых кур, белую пыль (kur) и белые кудри уже написала Ларf, и повторятся не буду.

Comment: Я не написал об этой версии, потому что внимательно прежде изучил фото каурых лошадей. Как-то не очень на белокурых смахивают)))

Comment: @grumant, у моей девушки натуральный цвет волос, примерно того же оттенка, что у лошади на фотографии в ответе, а есть блондинки и посветлее (побелее).

Comment: Каурый - карий, то есть коричневый ( см. Срезневский, том1, стр.1380!)))

Comment: @grumant, http://ahorse.ru/kauraya-mast.html Ссылка на лошадиную энциклопедию с фото и видео каурой масти. При желании её можно назвать светло-коричневой, но блондинов в общем-то тоже.

Comment: Каурых лошадей отличает так называемый дикий окрас — ближе всего к масти лошади Пржевальского. Там светло-рыжий тон светлеет к низу туловища, а на ногах часто встречаются "зебрины" — полоски.

Answer (score 0):

Образовано от "белокудрый". Согласная "Д" с течением времени выпала.